# How can I don't create a database if the database exists with Room in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Normally I use Code A to create a database `Tasks.db` with Room when the app run for the first time, I hope that Room doesn't create the database `Tasks.db` again when I run the app again, how can I do?

**Code A**

```
val result = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            ToDoDatabase::class.java, "Tasks.db"
        ).build()
```

Comment: Create a Singleton class and access the Room from there. Room creates the database only one time, it won't be re-creating DB on each app start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is safe to use as it is. You'll only get a new `ToDoDatabase` instance that you can access your database file through, but the file on disk won't be erased and recreated if it already exists.

Comment: Does it mean that `Room.databaseBuilder().build()` will never recreate database when the database exists?

Comment: That's correct, that will just create an object that you can access the database through, but won't recreate the file on disk, i.e. you won't lose any data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use method onCreate() of RoomDatabase.Callback, which is invoke only the first time you create a data base:

```
val result = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, 
    ToDoDatabase::class.java, "Tasks.db").addCallback(dbCallback).build()
...
var dbCallback: RoomDatabase.Callback = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute {
            Log.i(TAG, "create database")
            result!!.getDao().insertAll(...) // add default data 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```